# Angular: DataList not updating display

Tags: angular, html

I have a template like below:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of inputs">
  <input type="text" list="datalist" name="datalist">
    <datalist id="datalist">
      <option *ngFor = "let i of dataListOptions" [value]="i">{{i-1}}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

And a TS file like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  dataListOptions: any[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.dataListOptions.push(123);
  }
}
```

When I update the dataListOptions in ngInit() or after it updates the DOM as I can see the new options but when I click on the input element I still cannot see newly inserted array data.

I tried using ChangeDetectorRef after the update but still no luck.

My question is that what should I do to make the options added after the dataListOptions definition visible. I can see them when I inspect the view but I cannot see them in a "drop down"

[image]

[image]

**---UPDATE---**

I just realised that ExampleComponent implements ControlValueAccessor. I have no idea why it was added nor how it works so I need to do some more investigations because it looks like it's involved somehow in updating the display or the domain

**---UPDATE---**

The input is in a loop

Comment: What version of angular you are using ?

Comment: I am using 7.2.5

Comment: strange .. i am not able reproduce it see : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2lruf8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, that means I have to strip down my class to find out what functionality could be breaking the display update. Let me go check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why the display is not consitent with the inspected element but all I had to do is add `[attr.list]="'datalist'+x"` to the `datalist` and make every element's id somehow unique.

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of inputs">
  <input type="text" [attr.list]="'datalist'+x" id="input{{x}}" name="input{{x}}">
    <datalist id="datalist{{x}}">
      <option *ngFor = "let i of dataListOptions" [value]="i">{{i-1}}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have initialise array with value and angular could not detect for latest one

Try to empty array and refill it again like

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  dataListOptions: any[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
          this.dataListOptions=[]; // this is main part of working code
     for (var i =0; i <=6; i++) {
        this.dataListOptions.push(i);
          }
     this.dataListOptions.push(123);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is just because DOM is rendered before you update your array. You can also try with display flag using *ngIf but though it is not valid way